# How to define override css based on the inline style only?

Tags: css, css-selectors

There is an element like this:

```
<td style="border: 2px solid red; background: darkred;"></td>
<td style="border: 2px solid blue; background: darkblue;"></td>
```

The only thing that is showing which is which is the inline style, which I assume they are defining based on an SQL query on the back end.

I am trying to write a css stylesheet to override this style (from the front-end, and without access to the back end of the site); but the only way to define it is based off the element's actual inline style, since there is no class or id.

I know that you can define css for certain non-css elements, such as `name` or `for` in forms, by doing like so:

```
td[name=thename] { /*css here */ }
td[for=thefor] { /*css here */ }
```

So how can I do it based on style?

Answer (score 3):

You can copy the inline styles within an attribute selector and then use an `!important` rule to override them, e.g.

```
td[style="border: 2px solid blue; background: darkblue;"] {
    background: lightgray !important;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Dwew3/1/

Comment: This one would work too, but if the inline-styles change, will that break it?  Not that mine is much better, since it requires IE9 or higher, which cuts out quite a few people.  +1 though!

Answer (score 0):

For newer browsers you could use the nth child selector, and add !important to the styles.

```
td:nth-child(even) { background-color:blue !important; }
td:nth-child(odd) {background-color:black !important; }
```

I have an example in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mathieujonson/RVuS5/1/).  Unfortunately it doesn't work in older browsers.  If you can use javascript or jQuery, you can do essentially the same thing with better browser support.

Comment: I edited my fiddle, I had my even and odd backwards.